# a better way to swap values of text inputs?

Tags: jquery

I have an email sign up and search box that have the label inside the box, IE the email box says "sign up" inside the input. When you click in the box the value is removed allowing you to enter your email, if you enter nothing and click out, the "sign up" re appears. I am using the following code:

```
$(function() {
    swapValues = [];
    $(".swap_value").each(function(i){
        swapValues[i] = $(this).val();
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == swapValues[i]) {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }).blur(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
                $(this).val(swapValues[i]);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

However, I get the following error in console and am possibly having issues with other scripts due to this. Ill know for sure when I finish debugging.

error
assignment to undeclared variable swapValues

Is there a better way to do this?
thx

Comment: I don't think i is the value you think it is when focus and blur are getting called.

Comment: It works but gets the error. do you know of a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you still need 2 Listeners

```
    $('.swap_value').focus(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'sign up'){
        $(this).val('');
      }
    }).blur(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ''){
        $(this).val('sign up');
      }
    });
```

I hope thats gives you an example of how to work with 2 fields:

```
<html>  
    <body>   
        <input type="text" value="sign up" class="swap_value singup"/>
        <input type="text" value="search" class="swap_value search"/>
    </body>
 </html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   //<!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.swap_value').focus(function(){
          if($(this).val() == 'sign up' || $(this).val() == 'search'){
            $(this).val('');
          }
        });
        $('.search').blur(function(){
          if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val('search');
          }
        });
        $('.singup').blur(function(){
          if($(this).val() == ''){
            $(this).val('sign up');
          }
        });
    });
    //-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works great. Is there a way to use the same function for 2 boxes, if($(this).val() == 'sign up' || 'search') or do I have to write separate functions for each? when I do this it replaces 'search' with 'sing up' on blur

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design if they have the same class the listeners will apply to bove of them BUT while you can say `if($(this).val() == 'sign up' || $(this).val() == 'search')`  ... ` $(this).val() == '' ` is always the same, so you need at least 3 listeners

Comment: Yes, both are ".swap_value". I get where I can combine the first       " if($(this).val() == 'sign up' || $(this).val == 'search') but not sure on the blur function, it keeps replacing the value with sign up how do you tie the search to the search listener?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design  Like i said,`$(this).val() == ''` will always be true for both input fields, so it will always apply, i will add something in my answer that may help you

Answer (score 1):

This may be too little too late, but I got your code to work with a slight modification:

```
var swapValues = [];

$('input.swap_value').each(function(i){

  swapValues[i] = $(this).attr('value');

  $(this)
    .focus(function(){
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == swapValues[i] ) {
            $(this).attr('value','');
        }
    })
    .blur(function(){
        if ( $(this).attr('value') == '' ) {
            $(this).attr('value', swapValues[i]);
        }
    });

});
```

Basically I'm now using `.attr('value')` instead of `.val()`. I'm not sure if that was your problem in the first place, but the above code is confirmed working on multiple text inputs on a single page.

Comment: thanks man, I still check all of these. I appreciate it and got it to work like you have it. thx again!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but there are new ways of doing this these days.  The `placeholder` attribute in HTML5 covers this functionality, though IE9 and older and Opera Mini don't support it.

**Example**

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Sign Up" required>
```

Note the type and required attribute.  Combined, browsers that support the `email` type will do a client side check for a valid email.  Browsers that do not support the `email` type will render a regular text box.  There is also a `search` type that provides an "x" to clear the search terms if needed.  It also reverts to a plain text box in unsupported browsers.

If you must support older browsers, the accepted answer can work as a fall back.